# where cells having (25%) expected count less than 5 than may be used Fisher exact test if not what test will b

Tags: fishers-exact-test

where cells having (25%) expected count less than 5 than may be used Fisher exact test if not what test will be used
example
Abortion history

Comment: Did you get cut off trying to type your question? This is incomprehensible.

Comment: in my table values are 0 also

Comment: Having zero observed values does not alter things

Comment: @gung I understand him to mean that he believes Fisher can be used, but if that is mistaken then what can he use. I agree the last two words do not seem to add anything.

Comment: I want to send some tables  for detailed information but I am unable to do so on this platform in ask a question inbox

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Fisher's exact test. You can also use chi-squared if you use simulation to get the $p$ value rather than relying on the asymptotics.

Comment: some cells are having its value zero or below 5 in that situation which test will be used. which test will be used when there are small numbers (below five) in table and cells have expected less than 5 above 20%  as I have heard that assumption is that we can use fisher exact test only when there are small numbers(below five) in table and cells have expected countless that5 up to 20%.

Comment: I think you have been misinformed. the observed are irrelevant and Fisher works irrespective of the proportion of expected below 5.

Comment: can we use chi square test  in 2×3,3×4,4×4 or  2×4 table. if expected values are above 5 and Fisher test if expected values are below 5. Some tables of my thesis in which some cells are having its value zero and some below 5 in that situation which test will be used. Somebody tells me that where is Zero in that case we can not use fischer exact test.My confosion is that if in3x4 table 2cells value is zero can i use fischer exact test

Comment: Thank you sir for clarification and guidelines for using test  and making clear my confusions about using Fischer exact test.

Comment: Yes, although Fisher discussed only the 2 by 2 table modern extensions are for any size.